# How to Include ASPX page in ASP.NET User Control

Tags: html, asp.net, user-controls

Is it possible how to include ASPX page in ASP.NET User Control?

I have use ajax modal popup extender in asp.net user control.in that place update panel not accept while i am running my program. It throws the error below:

```
Microsoft Jscript runtime error:'Sys.Extended.UI' is nul or not a object
```

but when I am using the same update panel in my ASPX page it works fine.

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post some of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how to use an ASP.NET User Control. User Controls typically don't include a full page HTML markup since they are used for embedding in ASP.NET pages. If you try to embed a full ASP.NET page in another full ASP.NET page without an iframe, you will have page rendering issues since the DOM parser won't know how to process the page content.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET